# How would I implement a funtion as a variable into a higher function in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket, higher-order-functions

I want to create a high-order function called `listfilter` that would take the following input

```
(listfilter greaterthan5 '(2  3  4  5  6  7  8))
```

that would then take my list and run it through the function that I chose, in this case, a function that detects if a number is greater than 5, and if it was it would return all the numbers greater than 5 in a list:

```
output: (6 7 8)
```

Here is an example of a simple greater than function

```
(define greaterthan5 (lambda (num) (if (> num 5)
                                          #t
                                          #f)))
```

I am unsure how to implement a function as a variable within a high-order function so any guidance would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [cond](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=cnd#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29) and recursion. That function is bind to symbol `f` and is recursively called on each element of list. When this call `(f (car lst))` returns `#true`, that element is added to new list.

```
(define (listfilter f lst)
  (cond ((empty? lst) '())
        ((f (car lst)) (cons (car lst)
                             (listfilter f (cdr lst))))
        (#true (listfilter f (cdr lst)))))
```

By the way, you can simplify that predicate:

```
(define greaterthan5? (lambda (num) (> num 5)))
```